# BNRPerson *mikey = [[BNREmployee alloc] init];

Tags: objective-c

Struggling with this command:

```
BNRPerson *mikey = [[BNREmployee alloc] init];
```

I know what the `*mikey` does and I get what is happening inside the two brackets, but what role does `BRNPerson` have?

Comment: I'm going to assume `BNRPerson` is the superclass for `BNREmployee`

Comment: Sorry, yes BNRPerson is the superclass for BNREmployee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BRNPerson` is a *base class* of `BNREmployee` (and therefore `BNREmployee` is a *subclass* of `BRNPerson`). When two classes are related to each other as a base class / subclass, the relationship is called **"is a"**. In other words, `BNREmployee` **is a** `BRNPerson`.

In practice this means that you can reference a subclass through a variable typed as one of its base classes. In your example `BRNPerson` is chosen as the type through which to reference `BNREmployee`. This practice is called *programming to interface*.

The same mechanism is at play when you make assignments like this:

```
UIView *btnView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

In this case, `UIButton` object is accessed through `UIView`, which is one of its superclasses.

Comment: What is the difference between a base class and a superclass? Can a class have more than one base classes?

Comment: @Willeke "base class" and "superclass" are synonyms, in the same way as "derived" and "subclass" are. A class may have more than one base class, because it is transitive: if X is a base class of Y and Y is a base class of Z, then X is also a base class of Z.